# Can't make terminal window visible to Google Hangouts

Tags: ubuntu, google-hangouts

I'll be teaching programming lessons via Hangouts and I'd like to be able to screen share my guake terminal window, yet it isn't visible to the screen selection window. Any ideas how to go about this?

I'm running Hangouts video as a Chrome extension. I'm running:

- Ubuntu 14.04
- Guake Terminal Version: 0.4.4-1ubuntu1
- Chrome Version 42.0.2311.90 (64-bit)